# Can PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS in Django be set to .5 days or hours?

Tags: django

I'm using Django's built-in Reset Password Views. As the title says, I wonder if I can set the `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS` to half days (for example 1.5)?

If not, I guess I could extend and customize the Django auth view that makes use of this variable, but I have not been able to trace which one that would be?

Comment: Based on [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L85) you can set it to a float, but it will **not** work. Since it calculates the `.days` of the timedelta, and that is an `int`.

Comment: There is an open [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28622) to allow values less than one day.

Answer (score 5):

If we inspect the [source code of the `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` on GitHub (Djang-2.1)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.1.x/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L44), we see:

> ```
> # Check the timestamp is within limit. Timestamps are rounded to
> # midnight (server time) providing a resolution of only 1 day. If a
> # link is generated 5 minutes before midnight and used 6 minutes later,
> # that counts as 1 day. Therefore, PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = 1 means
> # "at least 1 day, could be up to 2."
> if (self._num_days(self._today()) - ts) > settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS:
>     return False
> ```

So the current day, as well as the timestamp (`ts`), we see that these are integer that calculate the number of days. The [**`self._num_days(..)`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.1.x/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L85) is calculated as:

> ```
> def _num_days(self, dt):
>     return (dt - date(2001, 1, 1)).days
> ```

So both are specified in "full days" since January 1, 2001. You *can* specify the number as a float, but it will *not* work, since the difference at the left side of the equation, only changes after one day, hence `0.5` or `1` is here the same.

Since according to the [documentation of **`PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout-days):

> The minimum **number of days** a password reset link is valid for. Depending on when the link is generated, it will be valid for up to a day longer.

This setting thus acts as a discrete variable with as unit a day. Furthermore as we can see, the number of days is "quantized", which means that it can in reality result in 23 hours, 59 minutes, etc. extra.

Comment: Thanks for the hints and help!

Comment: See also Django ticket: Allow password reset token to expire in under a day code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28622 Problem was fixed in 2019-09, but unclear when it will be integrated to other release branches.

Answer (score 3):

in Django version > 3.0 `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS` has been deprecated. and now in the latest version it supports reducing the value of this timeout, so we can reduce it to the number of seconds a password reset link is valid for.

in your `settings.py` you can configure the same like below

PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = 259200  # Default: 259200 (3 days, in seconds)

for more info - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout